# minimale Sales_Order_Date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table salesinvoices

[image]

I need to take the minimale Sales_Order_Date and doing sum on the metrics `Order_Amount_DC/ Order_Amount_LC/ Order_Amount_Euro_Budget`

As result I will get

[image]

I try

```
select
  Sales_Order_Number_Id,
  Name,
  Sales_Order_Date,
  Customer,
  Local_Currency,
  sum(Order_Amount_DC),
  sum(Order_Amount_LC),
  sum(Order_Amount_Euro_Budget)
from
  salesinvoices
group by
  Sales_Order_Number_Id,
  Name,
  Sales_Order_Date,
  Customer,
  Local_Currency
```

How could I get use min (Sales_Order_Date)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code-

```
select
Sales_Order_Number_Id,
Name,
MIN(Sales_Order_Date), -- Add MIN to the column 
Customer,
Local_Currency,
sum(Order_Amount_DC),
sum(Order_Amount_LC),
sum(Order_Amount_Euro_Budget)
from
salesinvoices
group by
Sales_Order_Number_Id,
Name,
--Sales_Order_Date, -- Remove this column from GROUP BY
Customer,
Local_Currency
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select
  min(t1.Sales_Order_Date),
  t1.Sales_Order_Number_Id,
  t1.Name,
  t1.Customer,
  t1.Local_Currency,
  t1.s1,
  t1.s2,
  t1.s3
from
  (
    select
      Sales_Order_Number_Id,
      Name,
      Sales_Order_Date,
      Customer,
      Local_Currency,
      sum(Order_Amount_DC) as s1,
      sum(Order_Amount_LC) as s2,
      sum(Order_Amount_Euro_Budget) as s3
    from
      salesinvoices
    group by
      Sales_Order_Number_Id,
      Name,
      Sales_Order_Date,
      Customer,
      Local_Currency
  ) t1
group by
  t1.Sales_Order_Number_Id,
  t1.Name,
  t1.Customer,
  t1.Local_Currency,
  t1.s1,
  t1.s2,
  t1.s3
```